# woocommerce questions - trying to pic an ecommerce solution

Tags: e-commerce

I need to have a conversation with someone familiar with woocommerce.  Is there a phone number for support, i am willing to pay for the support call.

I have a company that messed up the redo of my website and is willing to rewrite it in either WordPress or Magento.  I told them wordpress and they are using woocommerce as my eCommerce solution.

I sell medical products and will use it as a catalog for my more expensive products but want a robust eCommerce site for the smaller products.

I am looking for:
1. excellent SEO and Filtering.
2. great newsletter potential.  nothing fancy but I need to be able to have a doctor inform me of a product that he needs or has to sell me and turn the email around to me list quickly and efficiently as this is how i source my used equipment.
3. i could have over 1000-2000 products.

There are more things that i need but that's why I would like to discuss them with someone who understands the product at a high level.  That's also why i like the WordPress backbone because I pretty much know what it can do.

Magento on the other hand seems to get great reviews from developers but not so good reviews from the people who work the site on a daily basis, huge file sizes, bulky code, slow and not so user friendly.

Please let me know if there is a resource that i can talk to. .  Thank you. Rick

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a phone number but you can contact WooThemes directly with pre-sales questions. Go to the site and fill out the [contact form](http://www.woothemes.com/contact-us/).

There are any number of consultants/developers who'd be able to help with specific questions. In fact if you have specific questions you can ask them here in the appropriate format. Of course there's no guarantee that you'll get an answer from this free resource.

As to your needs:

1. excellent SEO and Filtering.

I would suggest [Yoast's SEO plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-seo/).

1. great newsletter potential. nothing fancy but I need to be able to have a doctor inform me of a product that he needs or has to sell me and turn the email around to me list quickly and efficiently as this is how i source my used equipment.

WooCommerce doesn't provide newsletters, you'd need to integrate with another plugin or service.

1. i could have over 1000-2000 products.

2k products isn't out of line if they are simple products. If you're dealing with multiple variations on top of the 2k base you may have some performance issues. Depends upon your hosting environment and configuration (i.e. shared hosting, virtual private server, co-location).